# How to specify Cmake directory

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I am using Linux ubuntu 16 04 LTS
I uninstalled cmake ver 3.5.2 because it is too old, and I get 3.13.4

I followed this instruction found here: (Installing CMake from Binary Distribution)
https://www.osetc.com/en/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-linux.html

I have done all the steps, except changing directory, the cmake stuff are all in my home directory. However, my system is not picking up the new 3.13.4 version because it is not in its directory of cmake.

error message: bash:/usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory.

How do I let the system know which place to find my new cmake.
(I am an ubuntu user, not really into ubuntu, just using it for a specific project, I would appreciate if step by step or exact commands needed are written down.)

This is my current status of the cmake
[image: Environment Variable-last one is for cmake]

[image: The error when I want to use cmake]

Comment: There are some instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/610352/641475) for building and installing a custom version of CMake. Did you try these? Otherwise, it sounds like you can just update your environment variable `PATH` to point to the location of the new `cmake` executable.

Comment: May I know how do i update my environment variable path to point?

Comment: Please see the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/60219/641475).

Comment: I still don't get it.
the path for my new cmake 3.13.4 is
/cmake-3.13.4-Linux-x86_64/bin

Comment: Yes, so you can edit your `.bashrc` file to contain `export PATH="/cmake-3.13.4-Linux-x86_64/bin:$PATH"`.

Comment: See that question and its answers about adding the directory to `PATH` variable: https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path. Note, that after changing some of profile files you need either to logout/login or to "source" this file.